# Given a triangle. Find the possible isosceles triangle.

Tags: geometry

Given a equilateral triangle ABC on a plane, and given a point P in the same plane.

How much points P is possible in such way that APC, ABP, PBC are isosceles and non degenerate?

By symmetry, i could find just seven. The answer say it is ten. but i can not find the another three.

The points i found was:
(The baricenter)

(6 points at the straight line that contains the median, these points are outside the triangle, i think it is i)

[image]

Comment: Probably not, in such case P = B, PBC => PPC. This is not a triangle
@DavidMitra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two cases where an isosceles triangle can be formed:

1. It lies on some perpendicular bisector of the equilateral triangle;
2. The length of a new side is equal to the side length of the equilateral triangle.

so the 10 points are:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Very nice

Comment: +1 (also) : I also was blind to the 3 external points that are *close* to the triangle.